# Create A Simple Menu Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, menu

I wish to create a menu like this with jQuery:

1. A button is clicked which displays a div containing the menu options.
2. If something other then the menu is clicked while open the menu is hidden.

I can do part 1 easily enough but part 2 is what I am having trouble with.
I am using the following code:

```
$("html").click(function(){
    menu.hide();
});
```

However this closes the menu as soon as I click on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("html").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('#menu_options_div') && $(e.target).parents("#menu_options_div").length == 0)
        menu.hide();
});
```

`e.target` - original clicked element. Simply test if it is not a div with options/menu and if one of its parents is not that options/menu div

Comment: Thanks that did the trick however I didn't use "$(e.target).parents("#menu_options_div").length == 0" as I didn't see  how it was needed.

Comment: Once you have some elements inside menu div, target will point to that element iside menu_options_div, and not to menu_options_div. That is why I also test if clicked div is not a child of menu_options_div (well, that is needed if you have something inside it and do not want to close menu when some child is clicked)

Answer (score 1):

i am not much sure about your question but you can try this:

```
$('body').not('menuelement').click(function() {
    menu.hide();
});
```

Comment: This can't work. As you select all bodies that are not `menuelement`. Well... actually you simply select that same body. It will act just like this: `$('body').click(function() {
    menu.hide();
});` http://jsfiddle.net/sGzyj/

Comment: so even if you click on menu and menu is in body then it will hide the menu as well, so for menupart to be visible "menuelement" is supposed a div

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment is not clear. I'm saying that .not("...") will not ignore click on menuelement. It will just throw out "menuelement" from a list of previously matched elemens. But $("body") will match ONLY `<body>`.

Comment: yes exactly, if "menuelement" is a div which is inside body tag. And in "menuelement" is your menu then, when i click on menuelement then as it is in body it will also hide, so in order to overcome this i used .not("menuelemenet").

Comment: And it will not work. Because `.not` is not doing that. It simply filter out previously matched elements. $('body') - find one element, body. `.not('menuelement')` test if resultset of previouse query has elements matching `not` selector and throw them out.  In this case you just put a click handler on $("body"), getting the same result as initial OP's code